# How does wavedec function in matlab select shifts for a given scale?

Tags: matlab, wavelet

In matlab,for wavelet toolbox when we give as input some x, we are specifying the number of stages for decomposition and the mother wavelet,how does the algorithm actually performs the shifting operation for a given scale?

Comment: Do you mean the actual algorithms presented in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html) ? If so I guess you will have to look up the references given on the page or type `edit wavedec` to see the actual code, if available.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering my question, it was indeed helpful but not the way I wanted. The toolbox makes use of multirate filter banks for decomposition.Actually I need the specific shift and scale indices for generating a wavelet lattice, for further processing,is there anyway I can get those specific values